# Cannot implicitly convert delegate to list of int

Tags: c#, delegates

I am working with a C# list of type int and delegates as in the following script

```
foreach (binitem in bilist)
{
    if (item.bsitem.OType == OType.prm)
    {
        List<int> appList = item.apl.FindAll(delegate (binitem i)
        {
            return i.apl.Contains(p.pid);
        });                       
    }
}
```

The above script threw me an exception `cannot implicitly convert delegate to predicate

May i know where exactly the error is?

Comment: use lambda : ``FindAll(i => {return i.apl.Contains(p.pid);})``

Comment: can you use Linq instead of List.FindAll?

Comment: `apl` is a List<int>, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `apl` is a `List<int>` and your `delegate (binitem)` has `binitem` parameter.
If you use `List<int>.FindAll` method, then delegate should have an `int` parameter.

```
List<int> appList = item.apl.FindAll(delegate (int i)
{ 
   // logic based on i.
   return true; 
});
```